# Turn property access Expression into a predicate Expression

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to make a generic filtering class, that will receive a property accessor and check if it's within allowed values. So the signature of the filter would be:

```
class PropertyFilter<TItem, TProperty>
{
    PropertyFilter(Expression<Func<TItem, TProperty>> accessor, IEnumerable<TProperty> allowedValues);

    IQueryable<TItem> Filter(IQueryable<TItem> items);
}
```

and usage

```
var filter = new PropertyFilter<Entity, string>(e => e.Name, new [] { "NameA", "NameB" });

await filter.Filter(dbContext.Entities).ToListAsync();
```

The thing has to be `IQueryable` compatible, so I need to compose an expression. From an expression of form `x => x.Property` I need to create an expression `Expression<Func<TItem, bool>>` equivalent to `x => allowedValues.Contains(x.Property)`. From what I've seen I am able to do basicaly anything with the expression using Visitors and whatnot, but for one I don't know what are the rules of translating expression to SQL and what I cannot do or I break it, and also the use-case seems too simple to warrant that much code as would go into implementing my own visitors and testing all of that. Is there a short way to do this or maybe a reliable library that has already figured it out *and is compatible with .NET Core 3.0 and EF Core 3.0 previews*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this *should* work?

```cs
static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> Contains<TItem, TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TItem, TProperty>> accessor,
    IEnumerable<TProperty> allowedValues)
{
    var wrapped = new { allowedValues };
    var body = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains),
        new[] { typeof(TProperty) },
        Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(wrapped), nameof(allowedValues)),
        accessor.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, accessor.Parameters);
}
```

You should be able to pass the result of this to `Queryable.Where`.

Note that `wrapped` here is to add a layer of indirection that the receiving LINQ query parser might want.

Comment: Unfortunately, when querying an SQLServer dataset underneath the IQueryable I get an InvalidOperationException thrown from the depths of EFCore - `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Query.Pipeline.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateWhere` to be exact.

Comment: After a brief investigation the only thing different from an explicitly written expression `x => allowedValues.Contains(x.Property)` (which works) and the one constructed by your solution appears to be that `allowedValues` are wrapped inside an anonymous lambda capture object. I was also able to dynamically construct a singular `Expression.Equals` expression and then by chaining multiple `OrElse` statements for each allowed value emulate a `Contains` call. That however sounds like it could be inefficient on a real db.

Comment: @V0ldek actually, it is the other way around - it is the compiler-generated one that has an anonymous capture object - my version goes direct, and the query generator isn't expecting that :)

Comment: Graveli right, that's what I meant, sorry for being unclear :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, EF Core 3.0 **previews** are unreliable as any *preview* (beta) software. Moreover currently they are in a process of rewriting the LINQ query expression tree translation, so it's quite unstable and many things don't work, even though they work in the last stable EF Core 2.x.

So trying to workaround them at this moment doesn't make sense. It's better to stay on last stable 2.x and wait for official 3.0 release.

Anyway, what you are asking is called expression composition, and there are many post how you can do that, including some by me. The important thing is to use *parameter replacing* technique instead of `Expression.Invoke` because the later was working in pre 3.0 versions, but the former is known to work with all query providers.

So you need a small helper expression utility like this

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
        => new ParameterReplacer { source = source, target = target }.Visit(expression);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression source;
        public Expression target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == source ? target : node;
    }
}
```

and then a helper expression composing method like this:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<TOuter, TResult>> Select<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(
        this Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner>> innerSelector,
        Expression<Func<TInner, TResult>> resultSelector)
        => Expression.Lambda<Func<TOuter, TResult>>(
            resultSelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(resultSelector.Parameters[0], innerSelector.Body),
            innerSelector.Parameters);
}
```

With these helpers, the implementation of the expression in question (which luckily works in the 3.0 preview) would be simply:

```
return accessor.Select(value => allowedValues.Contains(value));
```

The benefit of composing the expression this way is that the result is exatly the same as if you were doing that at compile time, hence has a bigger chance to be supported.

Comment: While this works, I chose Mark's answer, simply because is shorter and easier to understand for me.

Comment: That's ok. The above pays in long term when you need to do your own expression processing in many places where building expressions from scratch is annoying, unsafe and error prone, which is clearly seen by the usage - one-liner here vs Mark's code which also was wrong initially (the helper methods don't count, they are created once). Anyway, if you are planning to do a lot of expression processing, helpers like these are must have, especially the parameter replacer. Cheers.